# Why do input fields spread apart when their height is smaller than 15px?

Tags: css, input-field

Why is it that my input fields spread apart when their height is smaller than 15px? I have a margin and padding of 0px.

Inputs with a height of 30 pixels ⬈
[image: Inputs with a height of 30 pixels]

---

Inputs with a height of 15 pixels ⬈ 
[image: Inputs with a height of 15 pixels]

---

Inputs with a height of 10 pixels ⬈
[image: Inputs with a height of 10 pixels]

---

Inputs with a height of 5 pixels ⬈
[image: Inputs with a height of 5 pixels]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dqt1o01o/)

```
<input type="text"></input><br/>
<input type="text"></input>

input {
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they exist within lines of text which is controlled by the `line-height` property.

If you set `line-height` *in the parent **block-level** element* then they will look the way you want.

Also, `<input />` elements are self-closing and while using the `<input></input>` syntax is valid in XML (and thus XHTML) it is not valid in HTML and some (older) browsers and other HTML DOM libraries may choke on it, so please change them to `<input />`-style.

Comment: Never knew that they are like lines of text. I was expecting them to act more so like divs. Thanks for making that clear.

Comment: @MaxMastalerz No, `<input />` elements are classed as "replacement elements" in the flow (along with `<img />`) which behave similarly to `inline-block` elements in that they exist as `inline` however they have their own predefined height which alters their parent line's occupied space, but not the line-height itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dqt1o01o/1/

I achieve this with deleting the `br tag` and set the input to be display block type. Here is full css:

```
input {
    height: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: `display: block` could be an issue if someone wanted multiple fields on a line.

Comment: You can share a real example, so I can take a look how this can be solved. Like an solution inputs can always be wrapped into another tag that are set to `display: inline-block`

Comment: Try using the display: block solution with this one: http://jsfiddle.net/dqt1o01o/4/

Comment: I'd rather update the html to contain a wrapper around and not use display block at all. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/dqt1o01o/5/